# How to build a package for my QML app?

Tags: compiling, packaging, qml

I want to build a package for my app, written with C++ and QML. For this I'm using Ubuntu SDK.
I'm working on Ubuntu 15.04.
Here is the project tree :

Player :

- player.qmlproject
- components (a dir containing a bunch of qml files)
- imports-->Models : libPlayerModules.so, plugins.qmltypes, qmldir
- pages (an empty dir for now)
- test (a dir generated by the SDK)
- Makefile (a dir generated by the SDK)
- Player.desktop (contains a qmlscene call with the imports argument)
- Player.png (app's icon, included in the .desktop file)
- Player.qml (the main qml file)

Some info about the libPlayerModules.so in case it would be needed: I'm writing this lib using C++11, it depends on Qt 5.4, sqlite3 (used through QtSQL), taglib, D-Bus. I can run the app without any trouble using qmlscene.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what type of package you wish to build.  I'm going to assume that you want to build a click package, suitable for installation on an Ubuntu phone.

If you're using Qt Creator with the Ubuntu SDK plugin, there is a "Publish" tab on the the left-hand side. Select that, and then click the "Build and validate click package" button.  The click package will be placed in your build directory.

To build a click package from the command line, first place all the files into the correct (relative) hierarchy in a temporary directory.  The `manifest.json` file must be in this directory.  Keep in mind that any architecture-dependent files must have been generated in an appropriate chroot.  You probably want your `make install` step to set this up for you.  Then run `click build /path/to/temp/directory`, and you'll get the click package, named with the appropriate values from the manifest file.

Click packages are very similar to deb files.  You can inspect their contents with file-roller, but only if you rename them to end in `.deb`.

For more details about building click packages, including some helpful commands for building in chroots, see this [blog post](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/blog/2015/04/13/inner-workings-sdk/).